# iOS SetNeedsLayout on thread

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Good Day,

I have a complex calendar control that needs to be redrawn using setneedslayout everytime i select a date item etc. I tried to run this in a GCD Block, but it never ran. However, when i run it on the main thread setNeedsLayout runs and works. However, this causes an annoying stutter/lag in my program that destroys the user experience.

Can I know what can be done? Can this be executed on another thread? Can I use an NSTimer or perform selector on another thread?

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    });
    @try {
        NSLog(@"New Thread");

        if (self.selectedDate) {
            [datesToReload addObject:self.selectedDate];
        }
        if (date) {
            [datesToReload addObject:date];
        }
        self.selectedDate = date;
        [self reloadDates:datesToReload];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDates:) withObject:datesToReload waitUntilDone:NO];
        //[self perform]

        if (visible && date) {
            self.monthShowing = date;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception = %@", exception);
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
        NSLog(@"Main Thread");
    });
});
```

Comment: Its the reloadDates operation that runs setNeedsLayout, and causes the issue. Currently, the above fix of running it on the main thread is of course still causing the lag

Answer (score 0):

All UI updates need to be run on the main thread, you can not change the UI from a background thread (it will have unpredictable side effects).

If you are having performance problems you should use `Instruments` to profile your app to find out what's taking the processing time and resolve that issue (for example, do you really need to reload all dates and what about it takes significant time?).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions, using the code example above:

1) You're calling reloadDates twice; even if the view doesn't successfully update until the second call using perform_selector, you're still doing the same work twice. This alone will double any UI lag you're experiencing from the reloadData method.

2) Use a lower priority queue for the bulk of the work:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    if (self.selectedDate) {
        [datesToReload addObject:self.selectedDate];
    }

    if (date) {
        [datesToReload addObject:date];
    }

    self.selectedDate = date;
    [self reloadDates:datesToReload];

    if (visible && date) {
        self.monthShowing = date;
    }

});
```

Inside reloadDates, put **only** the setNeedsLayout call in a main queue async block.

Once that's done, if you still have an unacceptable level of UI lag, you need to look at the view that's being redrawn and see how you can make it faster. Instruments' Time Profiler is a good first step to see where you're using CPU time during those redraw events.